# Email not sent in zend framework

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

```
Error occurred while sending mail in zend framework.

5.1.3 Invalid address^M

Following error occured:
```

#

```
0 /var/test/trunc/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(289): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(Array, 300) 
#1 /var/test/trunc/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(209): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->rcpt('') 
#2 /var/test/trunc/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail() 
#3 /var/test/trunc/library/Zend/Mail.php(724): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail)) 
#4 /var/test/trunc/library/test/Mail.php(71): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp)) 
#5 /var/test/trunc/library/test/Mail.php(881): test_Mail->sendEmail(Array) 
#6 /var/test/trunc/application/models/TTN.php(379): test_Mail->sendHistory(12882, '<log><message t...') 
#7 /var/test/trunc/application/controllers/TTNController.php(96): TTN->end(12882, Array) 
#8 /var/test/trunc/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(502): TTNController->Action() 
#9 /var/test/trunc/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(293): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('Action') 
#10 /var/test/trunc/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) 
#11 /var/test/trunc/application/Setup.php(339): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() 
#12 /var/test/trunc/application/Setup.php(127): Setup->_dispatchFrontController() 
#13 /var/test/trunc/public/index.php(4): Setup->run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

It seems that the MS Exchange server does not allow relaying, which means that emails from an external source (like a webserver) are not allowed to be sent.

This is supposed to help: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

I set it up the way it's described, but it still did not resolve my problem. I'm also unsure how to integrate the MX-Server into my web-application. Using it as Server-Adress in the Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp gave me the same error as before. Maybe someone else can clarify that with the additional information.

Comment: The MX record is just a security feature to verify the domain name of the email address. You can define which IP is allowed to relay mails in the Exchange (or any other) mailserver.